# Animation applied to 2 font-awesome icons only works on one even though the code is identical on both

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to learn some web development and I've come across this problem while following an online course. I've applied an animation to both "fa-pencil-square-o" and "fa-lock" and the animation only seems to work on the lock, even though the code is identical. Can anyone help ? this is the code:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Signup/Login</title>

    <!-- Place your kit's code here -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/545aa5df11.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light custom-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Signup/Login</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#mynav" data-toggle="collapse">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                    </li>                   
                </ul>                
            </div> <!-- collapse -->
        </div> <!-- container -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 content">
                <h1>It's always free</h1><hr>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div> <!-- col -->

            <div class="col-md-4 content">
                <div class="signup-cover">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <h3 class="form-heading">Signup</h3>
                                    <p>Account creation is totally free</p>
                                </div> <!-- col -->
                                <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-3x"></i>                             
                                </div> <!-- col -->
                            </div> <!-- row -->
                        </div> <!-- card-header -->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Enter Name...">
                                </div> <!-- form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Enter Email...">
                                </div> <!-- form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Choose Password...">
                                </div> <!-- form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" id="confirm" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Confirm Password...">
                                </div> <!-- form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block form-btn">Create Account</button>
                                </div> <!-- form-group -->
                                <a href="#" id="login">Already have an account ?</a>
                            </form>
                        </div> <!-- card-body -->
                    </div> <!-- card -->
                </div> <!-- signup-cover --> 

                <div class="login-cover">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <h3 class="form-heading">Login</h3>
                                    <p>Enter Email and Password</p>
                                </div> <!-- col -->
                                <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lock fa-3x"></i>                                
                                </div> <!-- col -->
                            </div> <!-- row -->
                        </div> <!-- card-header -->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form>                              
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Enter Email...">
                                </div> <!-- form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Choose Password...">
                                </div> <!-- form-group -->                              
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="button" id="login" class="btn btn-success btn-block form-btn">Login</button>
                                </div> <!-- form-group -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <a href="#" id="signup">Create New Account</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div> <!-- card-body -->
                    </div> <!-- card -->
                </div> <!-- login-cover -->
            </div> <!-- col -->
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- container -->



    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/simple.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

simple.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").click(function() {
        $(".signup-cover").hide();
        $(".login-cover").show();
    });

    $("#signup").click(function() {
        $(".login-cover").hide();
        $(".signup-cover").show();
    });
});
```

and style.css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f2;
}

.custom-nav {
    background: linear-gradient(left, #f93d67, #7047d7);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f93d67, #7047d7);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f93d67, #7047d7);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f93d67, #7047d7);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.custom-nav ul li a {
    color: #fff!important;
}

.navbar-brand {
    color: #fff!important;
}

.content {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.card {
    border: 0px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.card-header {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #7047d7;
}

.form-heading {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.form-control {
    border-color: #7047d7;
}

.form-btn {
    background-color: #7047d7;
    border: 0px;
}

.form-btn:hover {
    background-color: #7047d7;
}

.form-btn:focus {
    background-color: #7047d7!important;
}

.card::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    top: 5px;
    border: 0px;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    background-color: #7047d7;
    z-index: -1;
}

.login-cover {
    display: none;
}

.fa-pencil-square-o, .fa-lock {
    -webkit-animation: icon-animate 2s infinite;
    -o-animation: icon-animate 2s infinite;
    animation: icon-animate 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes icon-animate {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The fontawesome kit you are using does not have the fa-pencil-square-o icon.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/NathanHawks/nvtzukLd/1/